# Limiting Handbrake Using a Cgroup?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04, cgroup

I'm following a tutorial for cgroups, but they don't seem to be effective in limiting handbrake (A video conversion tool)'s performance.

I can't really multi task while it is running.

I've installed cgroup* from apt and run the following commands to create the cgroup (Following this tutorial: https://www.devinhoward.ca/technology/2015/feb/implementing-cgroups-ubuntu-or-debian):

```
sudo cgcreate -a sarah -t sarah -g cpu:limitgroup
echo 512 > cpu/limitgroup/cpu.shares
cgexec -g cpu:limitgroup handbrake
```

Handbrake still uses too much cpu though (I though the cgroup would limit it to 50%?):
[image: Too much CPU]

How can I fix the situation and make handbrake use 50% CPU?

Comment: Depending on what sort of encoding you are doing you could limit the number of threads being used by Handbrake...

Comment: why not tune the priority of the encoding process?

Comment: @cmak.fr Are you talking about the CPU scheduler and I/O scheduler that I set to the lowest settings in system monitor? I already did that :)